# Letter prefixed with trailing zeroes code format

Tags: excel, format

I have a specific code system that I use to control the current balance of electronics we have at the warehouse.
Each piece has its own code in the following pattern: TYPE-000001

TYPE is a 4-letter code that defines what type of equipment it is and then it contains a 6-digit number right in front.

I want to type only "type1" and have it fill "TYPE-000001". Can I achieve this with Custom Formats or do I have to go the VB route?

I have found `-000000` to work fine for trailing zeroes, but I can't find a way to add the text in.

Comment: You will need VBA for that - or a formula, but that will show the result in different cell

Answer (score 1):

As Ike is commenting, you need VBA to achieve that in the same cell as you are entering the input value. If you can do with having that value i another cell you can use this formula, where A1 refers to your input value ("type1").

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1,4))
    &"-"
    &TEXT(
        MID(A1,5,255),
        "000000"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to achieve it using custom format.
Either use formula and deal with result in different cell (i.e. provided by @Thomas Lilleng) or use `VBA`.

This short code would convert text entered in `A1:A20` range to your desired format:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A20")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Left(Target.Value, 4) & "-" & Format(Mid(Target.Value, 5, 1000), "000000")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Place it sheet code under *Microsoft Excel Objects*.

Result:

[image]

Comment: I was worried this would be the answer. Thanks for the VBA code, it works perfectly, sadly at work we only have access to Excel Web, which doesn't have VBA support, so I'll have to stick with typing everything in manually ): - Have a great day o/